# Validate formly angularjs fields are not the same

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I have dynamically added fields on click.

```
       addNewFiled() {
        let parent = this;
        this.scope.fields.push({

            key: 'field-'+parent.scope.fields.length,
            type: 'horizontalInput',
            templateOptions: {
                placeholder :'Enter Field',
                label: 'Filed',
                required: false
            },
            validators: {
                fieldFormat: function($viewValue, $modelValue, scope) {

                    let value = $viewValue;
                    if(value.length != 12){
                        scope.to.message = "Field should be 12 characters";
                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }

        });


    }
```

What I need is to validate the the value entered is not in another field in the validator, I tried looping through the model but its not efficient, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered this case once, I solved the issue using 2 maps
Basically, you will have 2 maps, one which will contain the index of the field mapped to the value of it, the second map will contain the value of the field mapped to the number of the repetitions of that value
In your validator, you decrement the number of repetitions for the previous value ( after done with other validations) and increase the number of repetitions of the new value and check if it's more than 1 then it's repeated.

In your Dialog define the two maps

```
    private valuesMap: any = [];
    private keysArray:any = [];
```

In your field, you inject a controller to save the index of the current field

```
     controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.index = parent.scope.fields.length-1;
                parent.keysArray[$scope.index] = $scope.index;
            },
```

then in your validator

```
    if(value) {


        if(angular.isDefined(parent.valuesMap[parent.keysArray[scope.index]])) {
            parent.valuesMap[parent.keysArray[scope.index]]= parent.valuesMap[parent.keysArray[scope.index]] -1;

        }

        parent.keysArray[scope.index] = value;
        if(angular.isDefined(parent.valuesMap[value]) && parent.valuesMap[value] > 0) {
            parent.valuesMap[value] = parent.valuesMap[value]+1;
            scope.to.message = "Value is already entered";
            return false;
        }
        parent.valuesMap[value] = 1;


    }
```

Hope this works with your scenario

Comment: Thank you, I will try this solution

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a validator on this, there is already default validation for field length through the minlength and maxlength properties in the templateOptions.

Simply do this:

```
templateOptions: {
                placeholder :'Enter Field',
                label: 'Filed',
                required: false,
                minlength: 12,
                maxlength: 12
            },
```

Comment: I know but i do this to specify my own message, and the question was not about the length , it was about validating that all the fields are not the same

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?  The answer is correct.  I work in it all day at work, pretty sure I know what I'm talking about.  You could simply put a watcher on the fields that would accomplish this.

Comment: It will check if there is the same value in two or more fields?

Comment: Honestly, the easiest way to do this would be to simply add the other values to an array and then see if the array contains the $viewValue, if it does return false in the validator

Comment: so now you see this answer is not for the question, and basically this way is the same as the way I mentioned in my question and  I said its no efficient, since the validator is triggered on each key down, you need a constant time of access here, if you look at the accepted answer he managed to do this

Comment: In such trivial matters, it's practically irrelevant what the Big O complexity is.  OK, so it completes in .0001 ms instead of .0003 ms...Wow, you saved a tremendous amount of time.  It probably took far longer to come up with that convoluted function than to just do it the simple way.  This is the difference between someone who knows theory and someone who programs in the real world for a job.  In trivial matters, Big O notation is irrelevant.  If you are looping through 100,000 columns or something then yes, it might matter.  This is the stuff that just makes me shake my head and laugh.

Comment: I consider your words offending, your answer is irrelevant to the question, and in my opinion your analysis is not accurate, the validator is triggered on each key stroke so please do the math. and I do not see that you are fit to judge whether I program in the real world or not since all you said is not convincing